# Compare nullable enum-values within QuickWatch works while running app throws exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, enums

I have a simple enumeration:

```
enum MyEnum { First = 1 }
```

I use this enum in the following code:

```
object i = 1;
MyEnum expected = MyEnum.First;         
if ((MyEnum?)i == expected) { }
```

Now when running this code I get an `InvalidCastException`. However when I enter this if-statement into quickwatch from VS I get the expected value of `First`.

The object `i`  comes from a databasde-query and can therefor also be `DBNull`. In this case I set it explicitely to `null` whereas I have to cast to `MyEnum?` instead of `MyEnum`.

What can I do to compare the nullable enum-value to my expected one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange solution: first casting to `int` and then to the enum works, obviously we have to unbox the object first in order to convert it to the nullable enum.

```
if ((MyEnum?)(int) i == expected)
```

However I still don´t get why quickwatch is able to do this.

Comment: Quick Watch uses a special version of the compiler and evaluator, which have slightly different rules.  This situation is substantially improved in VS 2015 with Roslyn.